# What caused the decline of Buddhism in Japan?

Tags: japan, buddhism

I'm trying to find fairly detailed information on the causes of the decline of Buddhism in Japan. The most detailed information I could find so far is Wikipedia, but it doesn't appear to go too in-depth. I have a feeling you could write an entire book about it.

In the Wikipedia article on [Buddhism in Japan,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_in_Japan) it says:

"With the Meiji Restoration in 1868, the new government adopted a strong anti-Buddhist attitude, and a movement to eradicate Buddhism and bring Shinto to ascendancy arose throughout the country due to the strong connections of Buddhism to the Shōguns.

During the Meiji period (1868–1912), after a coup in 1868, Japan abandoned its feudal system and opened up to Western modernism. Shinto became the state religion. Within the Buddhist establishment the Western world was seen as a threat as well as a challenge to stand up to. Buddhist institutions had a simple choice: adapt or perish. Rinzai and Soto Zen chose to adapt, trying to modernize Zen in accord with Western insights, while simultaneously maintaining a Japanese identity. Other schools, and Buddhism in general, simply saw their influence wane. The edict of April 1872 ended the status of the Buddhist precepts as state law and allowed monks to marry and to eat meat. This "codification of a secularized lifestyle for the monk coupled with the revival of the emperor system and development of State Shinto were fundamental in desacralizing Buddhism and pushing it to the margins of society"."

That's one reason why Buddhism declined in Japan. What did they have against the Shoguns?

Also from Wikipedia: "After the Sengoku period of war, Japan was re-united in the Azuchi–Momoyama period. This decreased the power of Buddhism, which had become a strong political and military force in Japan." It doesn't say why the reunification decreased the power of Buddhism. It's not a very detailed description of the decline of the religion.

Are there reasons that Wikipedia does not mention, because it's meant as a general-purpose knowledge site.

Also, Buddhism is often associated with funerals, which is likely a reason why some Japanese may shun it.

Comment: You need to clarify what you're asking about. The source you cited is discussing the period of State Shintoism, which was abandoned after 1945. If you're asking about the decline during this period, that seems fully covered by Wikipedia and you need to explain further why you think the wiki explanation is insufficient. If you're asking about Buddhism today, then that is much more to do with recent demographics and changing spiritualism than any pre-war history. `but it may have started after 1573` Why do you say that? Nothing you've provided suggest this.

Comment: Seems as though you're answering your own question, if indeed there is a question.

Comment: "After the Sengoku period of war, Japan was re-united in the Azuchi–Momoyama period. This decreased the power of Buddhism, which had become a strong political and military force in Japan." It doesn't say why the reunification decreased the power of Buddhism. It's not a very detailed description of the decline of the religion.

Comment: @RakeALeaf It is not clear what details are you missing. For the most it is trivial that if a state adopts a religion (state Shinto) where the head of the state is a literal god than other religions (eg Buddhism) will lose power.

Comment: I think you're conflating the decline of the temporal power of various Buddhist temples, with the decline of the religion in general. The unification of Japan that culminated in the Tokugawa shogunate destroyed the military (and thus political) power of Buddhist sects. Samurai rulers feared the potential power of populist religions and ensured they were subjugated to their own authority. However, most Samurai were themselves Buddhists, patronised loyal temples/monks, and the religion fundamentally continued to prosper until the rise of atheism.

Answer (score 0):

Japanese Buddhism was somewhat corrupt and deeply unpopular with many ordinary people who considered it exploitative and parasitic. As well as being of foreign origin, it was also associated with

1. The doctrine of non-violence which included a ban on the eating of 4 legged creatures. By contrast, successful Western countries ate meat, drank milk, and gloried in technological militarism. Furthermore, they were Nationalistic. Shinto did not have much intellectual leadership and could be interpreted as Nationalistic and concerned with the cult of the Emperor- as a unifying factor. By contrast, some Buddhist sects could have allied militarily with rebellious Provincial aristocracies.

It wasn't till the Nineteen Twenties and Thirties that an ultra-Nationalistic Buddhism could boast of strong intellectual leadership. Thus the initial phase of modernization was in a context where religious voices were marginalized.

2. A rigid Caste system including an 'Untouchable' caste. However, it was clear that the rigid division between the Samurai/bakufu military government and the peasants led to low agricultural productivity. The 'peasant sage' Ninomiya showed how productivity could be increased by encouraging peasant rationality and cooperation. It is notable that Ninomiya Sontoku was able to persuade the local Buddhist priest to take up fishing to provide cheap protein to the people. The other class which had been greatly alienated was the merchant class (considered even lower than farmers) which had woken up to the fact that 'Western learning', especially in things like Medicine, was greatly superior to the traditional product.
3. Buddhism was associated with certain superstitious practices as well as wealthy people squandering their capital on religion in the hope of getting reborn as a divine being. The wealth it had accumulated over centuries made it a target for hatred and violence.

Japan was only able to get on to the gold standard thanks to reparations received from China after a successful war. This naturally reinforced the rejection of Buddhism as a non-violent religion which kept a Nation poor and dispirited. India and China were on their knees, while Japan had commenced its rise to equality with the West.

Comment: This is largely opinion-based, neither able to explain why Buddhism was popular for a thousand-year or why it still exists (and practiced in one form or another by a large part of the population). You have much factual error (the cast system of Shogunate had mostly Confucian, not Buddhist), and  I suspect you also confuse cause and effect. The explanation is self-contradictory, telling that Shinto was successful because could support foreign values while Buddhism was unpopular because of its foreign origin (?). Sorry, it is not clear what you want to say.

Comment: Your reply is purely opinion based and factually incorrect. Buddhism was expensive for ordinary people so they destroyed shrines. Confucian ideology does not have Untouchability. Thus, Japanese Caste is Buddhist in this respect. I suspect you confuse cause, effect and wholly irrelevant information. What you want to say is not clear- presumably because your English is weak and your reasoning power leaves much to be desired.